# How do you make Sublime Text 3 open a file in a new tab instead of opening it in the current tab?

Tags: sublimetext3

When I click the file I want to open in Sublime, it is replacing the current tab I have open. It used to open it in a new tab.

Answer (score 91):

This is because you were only previewing the previous file. If you click on a file once in the sidebar, by default it opens in preview mode. Clicking another file will open *it* in preview mode, in the same tab. You can disable this behavior by double-clicking the file in the sidebar, by beginning to edit the file, or via the user settings: select **`Preferences -> Settings-User`** and add

```js
"preview_on_click": false,
```

then save the file. With this new behavior, you will need to double-click on a file in the sidebar to open it, and it will not close if you double-click another file.

Comment: Adding that didn't help. It disabled opening up the file and "previewing" it completely.

Comment: @MarkA that's exactly what I said in my answer. You can either have `"preview_on_click": true` where single-clicking a file in the sidebar opens that file in preview mode, and single-clicking on another file replaces the first file with the second. If you want to keep a previewed file open, you need to double-click it, then the next single-clicked file will open in a new preview tab. Alternatively, setting `"preview_on_click": false` disables preview tabs altogether, and you must double-click on a file to open it.

Comment: is there any other way to open a file with a single click?

Comment: It seems to be the default in my sublime version to open a file with double click in a new tab. I have stable channel Build 4126.

Answer (score 43):

Preferences -> Settings-User -> "open_files_in_new_window": false

Comment: I think that this directive is only available on MacOS. Any viable solution for Linux? Adding `-n` sort of works, but opens a new folder in the same tab, rather than a new one.

Answer (score 4):

Open `Registry Editor` (The easiest way to do this in all versions of Windows is to open the Run dialog box via `WIN+R`, and enter `regedit`)

go to :

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\sublime_text.exe\shell\open\command
```

change it from :

```
"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" "%1"
```

to :

```
"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" -n "%1"
```

Comment: and you should reboot it

Comment: `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text\command` open with use this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple python script to get files to open in a new tab with a **single** click.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import os

class NoPreview(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_load(self, view):
        if (os.path.exists(view.file_name())):
            view.run_command('save')
```

Save this script with a .py extension in your sublime packages directory.
(Usually `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User` in Linux)

Note: Make sure `"preview_on_click"` is set to `true` in Preferences > Settings, otherwise this will not work.

Comment: This works great. Makes it more like VScode. In Windows the path is: C:\Users\{username here}\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages

Answer (score 2):

On single click you preview the files. You can double click on the file to open them in a new tab.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply go to preferences/settings/preferences.sublime_setting.
Under this, after font-size(array), paste this `"preview_on_click": false`.
And you are done!

**Note:** After this, you have to double click to open any file.

Answer (score -2):

You must be having "show tabs" unchecked under the VIEW tab. Check it and you can open a file with a double click.

Comment: Not sure why this has been marked down. It is one of the reason that sublime text does not show tabs.